DETR and Deformable DETR Colab notebooks or Python scripts
I am looking for DETR and Deformable DETR Colab notebooks or Python scripts for transfer learning on my custom dataset (3k Images). I used Detectron2 for ablation studies on object detection, changing only the algorithm while keeping the dataset constant. The existing DETR&Defromable DETR return metrics as negative numbers or zeros.  One DETR implementation tailored for Detectron2 also has metric issues. I am interested in the applied aspect, not the algorithmic details. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
